# Regular expression with native characters in ASP MVC model validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I have model validation in my ASP.NET MVC2 project, and I want to implement validation on field containing last name of some person. 
This field can contain any native characters (just like Ś Ć Ó and others, from any language), but not special characters ( like &#$% ) and numbers.

Part of code, where I have to put it, looks like this:

`[RegularExpression("SOME REGULAR EXPRESSION", ErrorMessage = "Field invalid")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field required")]`

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative character group, such as `[^characters-here]`. The `^` indicates that the character group is negative rather than positive. The pattern should be similar to this:

```
"^[^0-9!@#$%^&*-]+$"
```

If you decide to ignore a dash character, place it at the beginning or end of the character class to avoid incorrectly specifying a range of characters. In the pattern above I've placed it at the end. Placing it at the beginning would look like `[^-...]`.